# Software Product Feature extraction from requirement text using Natural Language Processing

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I am creating an application that will extract software product features from natural language text and this is mainly based on Information Extraction. Here feature is "a user visible aspect in a product". I have read few research papers and what I have gathered is that they use parts of speech to start of this process.

In feature extraction what I am trying to do is to develop the relation of Actor-Action-Object like "System supports Credit Card".

I am using Stanford's Open IE for this but results are not coming accurate. My question is that what Information Extraction technique I should use to get good results and some one has already suggested me to use RDF graphs.

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: My process starts with segmentationof sentences then for one sentence tokenization, POS tagging and Lemmatization is applied along with this Open IE triples are extracted from the same sentence. 
Next thing is that from the triples I am keeping the NN part in Object and subject and VB part in relation, but after this for simple sentences the results are in some way meaningful but for complex sentences where a lot of commas are used the results are inaccurate.

Comment: Yes sure, but what does the *code* look like? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask